# Json:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc, classnotfoundexception, java-web-start

I'm trying to use JSON in Java Web. Transform List to JSONArray by invoking JSONArray.fromObject(), I'm sure my arguments are right, but thrown the exception as following:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.lang.exception.NestableRuntimeException
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1645)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1491)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:320)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:621)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:124)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2733)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1124)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1612)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1491)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:320)
    at org.vclub.model.json.Page2Json.getJsonFromList(Page2Json.java:10)
    at org.vclub.controller.TopicController.loadMoreTopic(TopicController.java:70)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:185)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:126)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:502)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:465)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:863)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:792)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:851)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:767)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

btw, Learning from the google answers, I have added required libs.

```
commons-beanutils-1.8.3.jar
commons-collections-3.2.1.jar
commons-lang3-3.1.jar
commons-logging-1.1.2.jar
ezmorph-1.0.6-sources.jar
```

It still doesn't work. Please help me.
Thanks in advance

Comment: `NestableRuntimeException` seems to be in `commonons-lang-x.jar`. Are you certain that you have added the jar files correctly to the classpath?

Comment: Without seeing your code, how to you expect us to help you find out what's wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check:

http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/

You need to have `commons-lang 2.5` in your classpath. At the moment you have `commons-lang3-3.1.jar` which does not have `org.apache.commons.lang.` package but has  `org.apache.commons.lang3.`.

Add `commons-lang 2.5` or `2.6` in your classpath and this will work.

Comment: Thank you! Your answer is helpful

Answer (score 0):

I guess your problem is here: `commons-lang3-3.1.jar`. You have added commons lang version 3. Take a look on the [home page of commons lang](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/):

> Note that Lang 3.0 (and subsequent versions) use a different package
>   (org.apache.commons.lang3) than the previous versions
>   (org.apache.commons.lang)

This means that your probably should use commons lang version 2.